# Does a vector copy/move each element to a new memory allocated once it runs out of memory

Tags: c++

My understanding of `std::vector` was that it had an amortized time complexity when something was inserted at its end. The reason for this Amortized time complexity is that because once a vector runs out of reserved space for new elements it would allocate (reserve) new memory space and copy/move(C++11) existing elements to the new space. Is this understanding correct ? I then came across [this](https://thispointer.com/deque_vs_vector/) article according to which I am wrong. The article states

> No Iterator invalidation happens in deque for insertion and deletion
>   at front and end because like vectors, deque doesn’t have to shift
>   elements from one memory to another in case current allocated memory
>   is not sufficient to store the newly added element.

Can someone explain if my understanding is correct or if I am not understanding the article properly ?

Comment: Can you make a small edit to your question, as to clarify that you are asking about the case where "current allocation is not sufficient", in other words, "runs out of reserved space", rather than "runs out of memory" (which is when allocation fails) [I answered the first form of the question, because I was pretty sure that's what you asked]

Comment: @MatsPetersson yes i meant runs out of reserved space

Comment: voting to close: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

Comment: @xaxxon this is a theoretical question and the ambiguities addressed by the responders have been addressed

Comment: There's nothing theoretical about it.  It's just a typo.

Comment: @xaxxon - Not a typo. I got an answer that addresses my question. I am sorry you have a hard time understanding the question.If you could tell me what is unclear ill gladly rephrase the question

Comment: The answer you accepted says it's a typo.   "I think it's as simple as a typo, which should be "because unlike vectors"."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's as simple as a typo, which should be "because **un**like vectors".

Your understanding that `std::vector` moves the data to a new allocation when it needs more space is correct.